# issue extracting html page's string using bs4

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a program to find song lyrics , the program is almost near to done but i have a little problem with bs4 data type , 
my question is how to extract plain text from lyric variable at the end of line ?

```
import re
import requests
import bs4
from urllib import unquote

def getLink(fileName):
    webFileName = unquote(fileName)
    page = requests.get("http://songmeanings.com/query/?query="+str(webFileName)+"&type=songtitles")    
    match = re.search('songmeanings\.com\/[^image].*?\/"',page.content)
    if match:
        Mached = str("http://"+match.group())
        return(Mached[:-1:]) # this line used to remove a " at the end of line
    else:
        return(1)       

def getText(link):    
    page = requests.get(str(link))          
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content ,"lxml")     
    return(soup)        

Soup = getText(getLink("paranoid android"))
lyric = Soup.findAll(attrs={"lyric-box"})
print (lyric)
```

and here is outout :

[\n\t\t\t\t\t\tPlease could you stop the noise,
\nI'm trying to get some rest
\nFrom all the unborn chicken voices in my head
\nWhat's that?
\nWhat's that?
\n
\nWhen I am king, you will be first against the wall
\nWith your opinion which is of no consequence at all
\nWhat's that?
\nWhat's that?
\n
\nAmbition makes you look pretty ugly
\nKicking and squealing Gucci little piggy
\nYou don't remember
\nYou don't remember
\nWhy don't you remember my name?
\nOff with his head, man
\nOff with his head, man
\nWhy don't you remember my name?
\nI guess he does
\n
\nRain down, rain down
\nCome on rain down on me
\nFrom a great height
\nFrom a great height, height
\nRain down, rain down
\nCome on rain down on me
\nFrom a great height
\nFrom a great height, height,
\nRain down, rain down
\nCome on rain down on me
\n
\nThat's it, sir
\nYou're leaving
\nThe crackle of pigskin
\nThe dust and the screaming
\nThe yuppies networking
\nThe panic, the vomit
\nThe panic, the vomit
\nGod loves his children,
\nGod loves his children, yeah!
\nEdit Lyrics\nEdit Wiki\nAdd Video\n
 ]

Comment: Please provide your traceback

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but in the regex getting the url, this part `[^image]` is a character class, not a phrase. If you change it to `(?!image)` it would then be a phrase. Beyond that, what do you mean by extracting the _text_? Do you mean those `\n` are literals, or are they just debug text representation of the line break control code?

Comment: by [^image] i want lines which not contains lines like this :songmeanings.com/image/PATH/TO/AN/IMAGE.png
and i meant by extracting to plain text some functions which does convert a html file to plain text , of course i know i can do it with sed and awk , but i really like to do it in my python program without using regex

Comment: @kato You'll need to one line of code to extract text from tags. see post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append following line of code:

```
lyric = ''.join([tag.text for tag in lyric])
```

After

```
lyric = Soup.findAll(attrs={"lyric-box"})
```

You'll get output something like

```
                        Please could you stop the noise,
I'm trying to get some rest
From all the unborn chicken voices in my head
What's that?
What's that?

When I am king, you will be first against the wall
With your opinion which is of no consequence at all
What's that?
What's that?

...
```

Answer (score 0):

First trim the leading and trailing [] by doing `stringvar[1:-1]` then on each line call `linevar.strip()` which will strip off all that whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

for guys whom like the idea , with some little changes finally my code is looking like this :)

```html
import re
import pycurl
import bs4
from urllib import unquote
from StringIO import StringIO


def getLink(fileName):
    fileName = unquote(fileName)
    baseAddres = "https://songmeanings.com/query/?query="
    linkToPage = str(baseAddres)+str(fileName)+str("&type=songtitles")
    
    buffer = StringIO()
    page = pycurl.Curl()
    page.setopt(page.URL,linkToPage)
    page.setopt(page.WRITEDATA,buffer)
    page.perform()
    page.close()
    
    pageSTR = buffer.getvalue()
    
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pageSTR,"lxml")  
    
    tab_content = str(soup.find_all(attrs={"tab-content"}))    
    pattern = r'\"\/\/songmeanings.com\/.+?\"'
    links = re.findall(pattern,tab_content)
    
    """returns first mached item without double quote
    at the beginning and at the end of the string"""
    return("http:"+links[0][1:-1:])

    
def getText(linkToSong):
    
    buffer = StringIO()
    page = pycurl.Curl()
    page.setopt(page.URL,linkToSong)
    page.setopt(page.WRITEDATA,buffer)
    page.perform()
    page.close()
    
    pageSTR = buffer.getvalue()
    
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pageSTR,"lxml")  
    
    lyric_box = soup.find_all(attrs={"lyric-box"})
    lyric_boxSTR = ''.join([tag.text for tag in lyric_box])
    return(lyric_boxSTR)
    
    
link = getLink("Anarchy In The U.K")
text = getText(link)
print(text)
```